# EF Core Will not delete entry even after eliminating cascading properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

To give  simpler version of my database, I have Attorneys, I have Cases and I have CaseParticipations, which, surprise-surprise, has two foreign keys.

Now, in my API, the delete method for Attorneys starts by first finding all of the CaseParticipations which reference it, deleting them, doing a _context.SaveChanges(), and only then trying to delete the Attorney itself.

Here's the issue. This never works.

I implement this api in a website built in blazor and whenever I try to delete the attorney, it only erases its case participations, but stops there. If I rebuild and rerun the application, now the attorney has no case participations and when I try to delete it, it works.

I've debugged and it seems to be a Sql Server problem, it occurs on the line _context.Attorneys.Remove(att), and it basically says it won't delete the attorney because it still has Case Participations which depend on it and I didn't set it to cascade delete.

But this shouldn't happen. The Participations were already deleted.

My attempted fix was to pretend the Attorney entry doesn't get updated and still has 2 case participations in its properties, which don't actually exist in the database, so I tried updating the attorney after deleting the participations but before deleting it, setting its Case Participations property to a new empty collection of case participation, doing a _context.SaveChanges, and relaoding the attorney from context att= _context.Find(id). Still nothing, the same exception is thrown.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem in EF Core 3.1?

Comment: Can you show the code that remove participant and attorney?

Comment: Neither EF Core nor SaveChanges are broken. We can't guess what's wrong with the code without looking at it

Comment: `deleting them, doing a _context.SaveChanges(), and only then trying to delete the Attorney itself.` that's a bug. EF Core, like most full-featured ORMs, caches changes and performs *all* of them when `SaveChanges` is called. There's no need for separate `Delete` methods. Sounds like you tried to implement the "generic" repository *anti*pattern and run into problems

Comment: `CaseParticipations` sounds like a class created to implement a many-to-many relation. If you want its records to be deleted automatically when either a Case or Attorney are deleted, you need to configure [cascade deletes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) in the database and entities.

Comment: Please supply the DbContext relations for these tables.

Comment: `...and I didn't set it to cascade delete` - why not just set it? When a many-to-many parent gets deleted, there is no point keeping the linking information in the link/join table (i.e. your `CaseParticipations` table).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

The code for the classes would just make things more compliated, so here's a short version:

ATTORNEY
int AttorneyId - id, primarykey
string Name

CASE
int CaseId - id, primarykey
string Description

CASEPARTICIPATION
int CaseParticipationId - id, primarykey
int AttorneyId - foreign key, non-null
int CaseId - foreign key, non-null

, and ofc, when I used EFCore to generate the DB context, it added a CaseParticipations property to both Attorney and Case.

Comment: AM I using an anti-pattern? I mean this thing isn't happening in the repo, the repo can only delete one record at a time. 

The client requests first the deleteion of each participations, then of the attorney. those requests get passed down to the API then to the DAL.